# How can I remove javascript from everywhere but the front page?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I tried using this in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($!is_front) {
    unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Performance wise, would it be as good to have the javascript that's on every page in theme.info, then use drupal_add_js on the front page instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update. Below are the update :

```
if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
      unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
    }
```

[function drupal_is_front_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7)

Reference Link : [Click Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81603/if-drupal-is-not-front-page?answertab=active#tab-top)